# Is there a way to retrieve corresponding data from JSON Output to show that data in a spinner?

Tags: android, json

```
{
  "Platforms": [
    {
      "PlatformNo": "1",
      "SerialNumbers": [
        {
          "Aplilevel": "1",
          "Version": "1.0"
        },
        {
          "Aplilevel": "2",
          "Version": "1.1"
        },
        {
          "Aplilevel": "3",
          "Version": "1.5"
        },
        {
          "Aplilevel": "4",
          "Version": "1.6"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "PlatformNo": "2",
      "SerialNumbers": [
        {
          "Aplilevel": "5",
          "Version": "2.0"
        },
        {
          "Aplilevel": "6",
          "Version": "2.0.1"
        },
        {
          "Aplilevel": "7",
          "Version": "2.1.x"
        },
        {
          "Aplilevel": "8",
          "Version": "2.2.x"
        },
        {
          "Aplilevel": "9",
          "Version": "2.3"
        },
        {
          "Aplilevel": "10",
          "Version": "2.3.3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "PlatformNo": "3",
      "SerialNumbers": [
        {
          "Aplilevel": "11",
          "Version": "3.0.x"
        },
        {
          "Aplilevel": "12",
          "Version": "3.1.x"
        },
        {
          "Aplilevel": "13",
          "Version": "3.2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "PlatformNo": "4",
      "SerialNumbers": [
        {
          "Aplilevel": "14",
          "Version": "4.0"
        },
        {
          "Aplilevel": "15",
          "Version": "4.0.3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The JSON shown above is the output that I need to show in the PlatformNo's spinner. When I select one item, then do I need to get the corresponding API levels in another spinner? Can anyone help me please to get this solved? I'm trying below to get it, but I'm unable to get it correct. I'm getting the last values only in the next spinner. Is there a way to check this? Please help me.

```
String[] platfromno,apilevel;
Spinner splatform,sapilevel;  
JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject("Result");
JSONArray platformObject = customerObject.getJSONArray("Platforms");
String parray = customerObject.getString("Platforms");
System.out.println("String of Platforms array is " + parray);

for (int i = 0; i < productNameObject.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject e = productNameObject.getJSONObject(i);
    platformno[i] = e.getString("PlatformNo");
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerPlatfromNo =
        new ArrayAdapter<String>( this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                platformno);

    splatform.setAdapter(spinnerPlatfromNo);
    JSONArray serialNumberObject = e.getJSONArray("SerialNumbers");
    apilevel= new String[serialNumberObject.length()];
    splatform.setOnItemSelectedListener(
        new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                            View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                System.out.println("selected Item position is  " +
                    splatform.getSelectedItemPosition());
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
    });

    // if (splatform.getSelectedItemPosition()) {

    for (int j = 0; j < serialNumberObject.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject e1 = serialNumberObject.getJSONObject(j);
        apilevel[j] = e1.getString("Aplilevel");
    // }
    }
```

Comment: you r having problem with parsing or spinner logic...?

Comment: i'm the platform number correct but the api levels are only the last apilevels i'm getting so i think it here how to check the condition for parsing to get appropriate data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After trying alot i got solved the twister.

```
String[] platfromno,apilevel;
Spinner splatform,sapilevel;


    JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject("Result");
    JSONArray platformObject = customerObject
                        .getJSONArray("Platforms");

                for (int i = 0; i < platformObject.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject e = platformObject.getJSONObject(i);

                    platformno[i] = e.getString("PlatformNo");


                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerPlatfromNo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                            platformno);

                    splatform.setAdapter(spinnerPlatfromNo);

                    JSONArray serialNumberObject = e
                            .getJSONArray("SerialNumbers");

                    apilevel= new String[serialNumberObject.length()];


                    splatform.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                            System.out.println("selected Item position is  "
                                    + splatform.getSelectedItemPosition());

                fillApiLevel();

                        }

                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });


        public void fillApiLevel(){

                JSONArray serialNumberObject = null;
        try {
            serialNumberObject =platformObject .getJSONObject(
                    splatform.getSelectedItemPosition()).getJSONArray(
                    "SerialNumbers");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        platfromno = new String[serialNumberObject.length()];
        apilevel = new String[serialNumberObject.length()];

        for (int j = 0; j < serialNumberObject.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject e1 = null;
            try {
                e1 = serialNumberObject.getJSONObject(j);

                platfromno[j] = e1.getString("Aplilevel");
                apilevel [j] = e1.getString("Version");


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerSerialNumer = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    platformno);

            sSerialNo.setAdapter(spinnerSerialNumer);
                    }
```